# how to show cancel button of searchbar?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I want to hide the Navigation Bar of my page when the user start editing on the searchbar, I also want to show a cancel button.
It is done but my cancel button is not accessible when I bring up the UISearchBar 
Thanks to All.

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=TRUE;
    CGRect r=self.view.frame;
    r.origin.y=-44;
    r.size.height+=44;

    self.view.frame=r;

    searchBar.showsCancelButton=TRUE;

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34692277/how-to-exit-from-the-search-on-clicking-on-cancel-button/42020784 go through this and you will get better understanding..

Answer (score 38):

### Objective C

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = TRUE;
    CGRect r = self.view.frame;
    r.origin.y = -44;
    r.size.height += 44;
    self.view.frame = r;

    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
}


-(void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
}
```

### Swift

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = true
    var r = self.view.frame
    r.origin.y = -44
    r.size.height += 44

    self.view.frame = r
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: No setting that shows the cancel button while editing... nice miss apple :\

Answer (score 14):

Use this code to show/Hide  the cancel Button in `SearchBar`

As user will start the Editing in SearchBar SHow the Cancel Button.

Below methods will only be accessible if you have set the delegate of `SearchBar` properly.

```
 -(void) searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
  {
    //This'll Show The cancelButton with Animation  
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
    //remaining Code'll go here
  }
```

Hide The `CancelButton` as User Click on Cancel Button

```
 - (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *) searchBar
 {
        //This'll Hide The cancelButton with Animation  
      [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
       //remaining Code'll go here
 }
```

Comment: Nice answer! One other thing that I will like to know.
Can I display programmatically the grey overlay when TextBeginEditing?

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

```
searchBar.showsCancelButton=YES;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4:**

Below 2 lines of code worked for me to show cancel button:

```
searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
```

Calling inside `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing()` method will show cancel button after clicking on search bar.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for showing `cancel` button. It will show button when you will enter text in  `searchBar`.

```
-(void) searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use UISearchDisplayController, that will hide navigation bar automatically for you.
Here is the code,

```
-(void) createSearchBar
{
     _searchBar          = [[SearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
     _searchBar.delegate = self;
     [self.view addSubview:_searchBar];

    searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:_searchBar contentsController:self];
    searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 10;
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.sectionFooterHeight = 0;
    [searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView setSeparatorColor:[Color whiteColor]];  
}
```

You will have to implement protocols  UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource    in .h file.

also _searchBar  & searchDisplayController  are variables defined in .h file.

Comment: As of iOS 8 you should no longer use UISearchDisplayController. Use UISearchController instead.