# How to exit from the search on clicking on Cancel button?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have a search bar with cancel button. But when I click on Cancel button it doesn't close the search bar. How can I make that on click on Cancel it will return search bar to the first state?

If you have any questions - ask me, please

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You need to implement the UISearchBarDelegate :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
```

Set the search bar delegate to self

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        searchBar.delegate = self
```

and then implement the butCancelSearchAction delegate function to do whatever you need to do to cancel the search action and reset the search text:

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    // Do some search stuff
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    // Stop doing the search stuff
    // and clear the text in the search bar
    searchBar.text = ""
    // Hide the cancel button
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
    // You could also change the position, frame etc of the searchBar 
}
```

Comment: No, I did not ask this. On click on Cancel I want to close my search. For example, I have a searchBar. When I tap on it cancel button appears and the size of Bar changes. Right? So, on cancel I want to return it to the initial look

Comment: In searchBarCancelButtonClicked you can implement whatever you need to happen when cancel is tapped, resetting the search bar to its initial state.  I've updated my answer slightly to show this.

Comment: To hide the cancel button you use  searchBar.showsCancelButton = false in in searchBarCancelButtonClicked.

Comment: You can call the searchBarTextDidEndEditing() function in the searchBarCancelButtonClicked() function.

Answer (score 18):

```
class MyController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {
    // Called when search bar obtains focus.  I.e., user taps 
    // on the search bar to enter text.
    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.text = nil
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = false

        // Remove focus from the search bar.
        searchBar.endEditing(true)

        // Perform any necessary work.  E.g., repopulating a table view
        // if the search bar performs filtering. 
    }
}
```

Comment: it works, thanks. But after cancel button is clicked, the filtering isnt removed, so user can not see other table entries anymore. So reloading the table with self.Table.reloadData() can help

Answer (score 7):

Try. It works fine.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
        //write other necessary statements
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.text = nil
        searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)

        // Remove focus from the search bar.
        searchBar.endEditing(true) 
    }
}
```

Comment: Barely changed from orangemako's answer, so should just be a comment. Note that `searchBar: UISearchBar` has now become `_ searchBar: UISearchBar` in both cases.

Answer (score 4):

I am also come across with this problem, in my case after searching any item from table view than click one of the result item it's opened details view but search bar does not disappeared. I use [Nicat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43347184/1746258) with a little changes, here is my version:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    searchController.isActive = false
    self.searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchController.searchBar)

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Very quick and simple. Just conform to the `UISearchBarDelegate` protocol, and then implement this function in your class:

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

**`resign` means that it will quit**

**`FirstResponder` is the focus of the view**

In conclusion, this takes focus away from the search bar, effectively canceling it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement the **UISearchBarDelegate**.

The `UISearchBarDelegate` protocol defines the optional methods you implement to make a `UISearchBar` control functional. A `UISearchBar` object provides the user interface for a search field on a bar, but it’s the application’s responsibility to implement the actions when buttons are tapped. At a minimum, the `delegate` needs to perform the actual search when text is entered in the `textField`. [Read this](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/index.html)

**In Objective C**

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

     [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];

}
```

**In Swift :**

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    self.searchDisplayController.setActive(false, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: there is not `setActive` in UISearchBar in Swift =/

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't what I want. It did not do anything. On click on Cancel I want to close my search. For example, I have a searchBar. When I tap on it cancel button appears and the size of Bar changes. Right? So, on cancel I want to return it to the initial look

Comment: can you upload screenshot or show your code? what you have used UISearchControlllor os UISearchbar ?

Comment: Before: http://imgur.com/WBfZ4dd

Later: http://imgur.com/qvEPrUa

and it still stays like this even when I press cancel button

Comment: show your code first i wanna know what you have used Search Controller or SearchBar ?

Comment: I just have added your code inside of cancel button clicked

Comment: have you set delegate debug and see whether this method called or not ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
searchController.active = false
```

Comment: Please add some explanation around your post, stating what you believe was likely wrong and why your proposal will solve that issue.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3

```
func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    return true
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}

The Cancel button appears only when the user start entering characters in the field.
```

Comment: `func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}
`

Looks like it will create an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

When you tap the cancel button, the `searchBar` sees it like you've got a new thing to search, that's why if you put `resignFirstResponder()` on the `cancelButton` clicked it won't work, because after this it will call  `didBeginText`.

So I put a condition in `didBeginText`, so when the string in the search has less or 0 characters it will resign the first responder. Just like this:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText.characters.count < 1 {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

It's an easy approach and works as well. 
Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

For Objective-C solution

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    if(@available(iOS 11.0, *)){
        [self.navigationController.navigationItem.searchController.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    }
    // reload your table or whatever you want.
    // searchController is available after the iOS 11, so it will be good to use @available check
}
```