# Removing focus from Search Controller when view is loaded

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I have a simple TableView with a search bar added. Everything works fine, except that when the view comes up (it's the first view in the app), the search bar is focused (or appears so), so that it shows the "Cancel" button (see image).
I've tried setting the tableview as first responder, calling resignFirstResponder on the search controller etc.
If you tap on the search bar and then hit cancel, the focus is removed and everything's fine - the "Cancel" button goes away.
Any ideas on why this is and how can I show a search bar that's not focused?

[image: App view as it first appears when app is loaded]

Comment: can you post your code, so that we can help you.

Comment: In `viewdidload` set `searchBar.setShowsCancelButton = false`.When searchbar begin editing set `searchBar.setShowsCancelButton = true` and when end editing set back to `searchBar.setShowsCancelButton = false`

Comment: Check this for detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028665/how-to-show-cancel-button-of-searchbar

Comment: Thanks, I realize I can do that, but I thought this functionality comes out of the box. For example, in the current code I have, if I tap in the search bar and then tap cancel, the cancel button goes away! And then comes back when I tap the search bar again. So the search bar knows how to show and hide the button on its own. It just shows it when the view is loaded with the cancel button for some reason. So I'd like to understand why without overriding the default behaviour unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the image, your textfield is not first responder and you just don't want to see cancel button

you can set `searchBar.setShowsCancelButton = false`

or in storyboard, uncheck `Shows Cancel Button`

[image]

then if you want to show cancel button during editing, check the `UISearchBarDelegate` methods:

> func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing

and set `searchBar.setShowsCancelButton = true`

> func searchBarCancelButtonClicked

and set `searchBar.setShowsCancelButton = false`

Comment: Thanks, that's similar to what Sudhir told me. Please see my reply to him. Actually, I don't think the search bar is the first responder, because resigning the first responder on it in viewDidLoad doesn't change anything...

Comment: based on your picture, its not. The cancel button is removed now right? What is your problem now?

Comment: Ted,
Sorry if I wasn't clear. The situation now is as follow: when the App first starts up, the view is as it is in the screenshot I posted. Adding resignFirstResponder in viewDidLoad for the search bar doesn't change this.
Now, If the user taps on the search bar, it becomes active, and the user can search, with the cancel button shown. If the user then taps the cancel button, the search is cancelled, and the Cancel button disappears and the search bar returns to full width - as it should have been when the app starts up.
So, my only problem is on startup - why is the cancel button there?

Comment: I marked you answer as solving my problem, because it will - I just want to understand why I need to do this manually (adding and removing the cancel button).

Comment: In my opinion, everyone has their own preference when using the default cancel button or not and Apple gives us enough control to hide and show it when needed. You can manipulate other views when UISearchBarDelegate methods are called. UISearchBar has been available since iOS2. You can ask them to update :)

Answer (score 3):

Add **searchBar.resignFirstResponder()** in viewDidLoad() method.

-Good Luck.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work. It's not the first responder apparently.